# Remove duplicates from fact table to calculate measure correctly

Tags: sql, t-sql, data-warehouse, cube

I'm very new to data warehousing and dimensional modelling. For a uni project I started out with a database that I need to turn into a data warehouse for analyses. To end up with a clean star schema, I had to denormalize a few tables into 1 fact table. The downside to this is the amount of redundancy.

Below is a part of the data from the fact table:

[image]

A voyage consists of multiple shipments, and a shipment can consist of multiple different items. In this example, containers 1-2000 of shipment 1 contain item 3, and containers 2001-5000 contain item 1. The total amount of containers for this shipment is 5000, obviously. However, for data analysis purposes, I need to calculate a measure for the total amount of containers per voyage. This presents a problem with the current fact table, because I have a record for each different item. So for voyage 1, the actual total amount should be 9200, but because of the duplication I'll end up with 19400, leading to an incorrect measure.

I need to find a way to get rid of the duplicates in my calculation, but I can't find a way to do so. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `count(distinct...`? You can start to see why a lot of people don't like star schemas...

Comment: Thanks, but distinct wouldn't be correct anymore where there's multiple shipments with the same amount of containers.

Comment: It would be if you were grouping by shipment. If not then you need to group by shipment inside a CTE/derived table, then group again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you'll need to do is group by your shipments ([CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), [inner query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/subqueries?view=sql-server-ver15), [temp table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), etc) to get the number of containers per shipment, then group by your voyages to get the number of containers per voyage.

Here's an example with an inner query:

```
SELECT voyage_id, SUM(num_ship_containers) AS num_voyage_containers
FROM (
  SELECT voyage_id, shipment_id, MAX(container_end) AS num_ship_containers
  FROM ShippingWarehouse
  GROUP BY voyage_id, shipment_id
) AS ship_data
GROUP BY voyage_id;
```

> | voyage_id | num_voyage_containers |
> | --- | --- |
> | 1 | 9200 |

[Try it out!](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0f87f/6)

Comment: IMO, what you need to do is design your data warehouse properly so that you can easily use it to answer the analytical queries you have. Having duplicate values is a clear sign that there is a design issue and trying to solve them with (relatively) complex SQL queries is not the solution

Comment: Agreed. Flattening a relational structure doesn't make sense if you need to restore it to make sense of the data in your warehouse.